# Windows Service does not start on some local systems

Tags: c#, windows-services, network-programming

I have created a windows service and installed it on 3 computers in a network.

It works fine on 2 of them but it has problem with the third one.

I have used Event Log to find out where the problem is, however it inserts logs just for the first time that i restart the system and also i have found that it just performs `InitializeComponent()` command in its constructor.

**Note:** My service should insert the login and logout of all accounts in a network and needs 3 dependencies that they start successfully before my service starts.

**Edit:**
I have followed this article to create my service.The following code is just the constructor of the service.

```
ComAdminCatalogClass comAdmin = new ComAdminCatalogClass();
ICatalogCollection subCollection;

//Service Constructor
Public Service1()
{
   try
   {
      EventLog.WriteEntry("Service1","1");
      InitializeComponent();
      EventLog.WriteEntry("Service1","2");

      subCollection = (ICatalogCollection)comAdmin.GetCollection("TransientSubscriptions");

      SubScribToEvent(subCollection, "Logon");
      SubScribToEvent(subCollection, "Logoff");
   }
   catch (Exception exp)
   {
      EventLog.WriteEntry("Service1",exp.Message);
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more information. Maybe add an exception handler around or inside InitializeComponent and log the details of any thrown exceptions.

Comment: @akton,I have used try..Catch to handling the exception and wrote the exception message in Event Log but no logs inserted that shows what is the problem.

Comment: Then you know it is not getting that far. Are all the dependant assemblies present? What happens when you run the exe directly?

Comment: @MitchWheat, I do not have permission from my boss to place my service in this system,so i should write codes again if i need them.However i have wrote the constructor of my service.

Comment: @akton, I have run the exe of my service but nothing happened.

Comment: @akton,Excuse me,I did not see the event logs.A log with the following description inserted when i tried to run exe file: "Service cannot be started.The service process could not connect to service controller".what does this message say?

Comment: It means the service had an error before it was able to connect to the service controller. However, this may also occur when the EXE is run outside of a service, such as by pressing F5 in Visual Studio or from the command line

Comment: @M_Mogharrabi, can you debug the service? [System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch.aspx) can help you find what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot @akton, I have found the solution by run the exe of my service!!

It was too foolishly.The Event Viewer of the third system was full!!! I cleared all logs from it and my service works fine now in all three systems.

You can follow [these steps](http://www.fanhow.com/knowhow%3aClear_Events_in_Windows_XP_31771266) to clear all Events